# Error when publish fat jar to private sonatype nexus repository

Tags: scala, sbt, nexus, sonatype, sbt-sonatype

I am using sbt 1.1.5 and get the following error when I run `sbt publish`:
`[info] published project_2.11 to http://localhost:8081/repository/maven-releases/project/project_2.11/1.4.1+0-6b38d149+20180906-1611/project_2.11-1.4.1+0-6b38d149+20180906-1611.pom
[error] java.net.SocketException: Broken pipe (Write failed)`
Conf in `build.sbt`:

```
resolvers += "Nexus" at "http://localhost:8081/repository/maven-releases/"

publishMavenStyle := true

publishTo := {
  val nexus = "http://localhost:8081/repository/maven-releases/"
  if (isSnapshot.value)
    Some("snapshots" at nexus + "")
  else
    Some("releases"  at nexus + "")
}

credentials += Credentials("Sonatype Nexus Repository Manager", "localhost", "admin", "admin123")
```

I am also using sbt plugins `sbt-assembly` and `sbt-dynver`.
The strange thing is that I can see sbt published pom file onto the repo, error happends when publishing the fat jar.

Comment: Given you are using a "local" nexus repository, have you any related log from the repo?

Answer (score 0):

I think the solution here will solve this for you:  https://support.sonatype.com/hc/en-us/articles/360000228868-Artifact-uploads-fail-with-broken-pipe-errors

Comment: "Links to external resources are encouraged, but please add context around the link so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there. Always quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the target site is unreachable or goes permanently offline." https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer